# Button style that can present multiple text strings?

Tags: silverlight, button, coding-style

I need to have a button style that will present 3 different texts of the binded stings. Now, I can easily pass one text string to Content Presenter where Content="{TemplateBinding Content}". I need to be able to pass 3 strings in a similar way to 3 either texblock inside button style or use multiple Content presenters. I am wondering how I can do this. Any ideas are highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom DataTemplate:

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="2" />
                <TextBlock Text="3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

You can swap out or change the layout by altering the StackPanel.

If it needs to be a Style, you could use:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding One}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Two}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Three}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then you'd need to define a custom class to pass the three values like so:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
<Button>
    <local:MyClass One="1" Two="2" Three="3" />
</Button>
```

Where local refers to the namespace of MyClass.

Comment: Thank you for the great info. I only have trouble to use the second approach where you ad datatemplate into style. I cannot do that on my end. I am wondering if you can provide more complete sample. I think I need to use this approach. thank you again. I highhly appreciate your help.

Comment: @vladc77 - Sorry, I was missing the TargetType from the Style.

Comment: I used before. It did not work. Do I have to have the data template inside Control Resources? Thanks.

Comment: @vladc77 - In general, it would go in the Window resources. The Style approach is only useful if you want to apply it to more than 1 button. Also, if you set the Style property of the Button, then the above implicit Style will not be applied (as the Style property overrides it). If you go the Style route, you have to use something like MyClass as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When I asked about having it in the Control Resource, I meant that it should be inside style and embedded into lets say grid resources that will hold all other parts like Visual State Manager and all other parts of the style. I have hard time applying datatemplate in a more complex style. Using your sample exactly like you presented is working.